# Logical / Relational Expression Optimization

Tags: c++, c, expression, logical-operators, relational

I need to optimize an expression of the form:

```
(a > b) || (a > c)
```

I tried several optimized forms one of which is as follows:

```
(a * 2) > (b + c)
```

**Optimization is not from the compiler's point of view. I would like to reduce the two >s to one.**

This is based on the assumption that 1 <= (a, b, c) <= 26

However, this works only for some cases. Is the optimization I am trying to do, really possible? If yes, a start would be really helpful.

Comment: What and why exactly are you trying to optimize?

Comment: I doubt (a * 2) > (b + c) is more optimal actually, at least if I correctly understand that you want to improve the speed of execution.

Comment: Did you know that the evaluation of `a > c` will be skipped if `a > b` if it's happening in an `if`?

Comment: To minimize the number of relational operations, and if possible replace the logical one as well, considering that I am dealing with numbers.

Comment: @AnotherTest: As mentioned in the question, it does not really work for all cases.

Comment: @Zeta: Thought about the order. But the exact one is not really known, i.e. both can be true, one pair of T,F, and one false.

Comment: But why are you trying to that? There's probably no speed gain, and no clarity gain either.

Comment: Because there are no side-effects which short-circuiting would prevent, the compiler could already be optimizing this into a single branch -- turning that logical OR into a bitwise OR.

Comment: @delnan: Just trying out a new technique, if it really exists.

Comment: @user2053912: You need to read your processors manual and check how many ticks an addition (yes, `a*2 == a+a`) will take in comparison to a simple comparison. However, I also doubt that this hack will be better. Did you try using compiler optimization flags?

Comment: @CoryNelson: This is not from the compiler point of view. Just need to find a way to minimize the no.of relational operators to one, and even try replacing the ||, all if possible.

Comment: Let `a=5, b=2, c=20`; OP's second expression doesn't look like an optimisation of the first to me.

Comment: So, you only need to know if a is greater than the smaller of b and c. What does (a > min(b, c)) compile to?

Comment: Side note - if a is between b and c and c < b more than 1/2 the time, then `(a > c || a > b)` would be more efficient. This is only really applicable if you have some statistics on the data.

Comment: I thought about that, but did not go further. Thanks.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: I guess, the relational operator needs to be rotated.

Comment: @roger_rowland `min(b,c) = (b<c)?b:c` (or something similar) - you're saving on the boolean operator, but not on the relational one. In fact, you lose out if `a` is greater than both, since you're still doing 2 comparisons, not just 1.

Comment: I'd use this: `a > max(b,c)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can come up with is this

```
char a, b, c;
std::cin >> a >> b >> c;

if (((b-a) | (c-a)) & 0x80) {
    // a > b || a > c
}
```

With `gcc -O2` this generates only one conditional branch

```
40072e:       29 c8                   sub    %ecx,%eax
400730:       29 ca                   sub    %ecx,%edx
400732:       09 d0                   or     %edx,%eax
400734:       a8 80                   test   $0x80,%al
400736:       74 17                   je     40074f <main+0x3f>
```

This leverages the constraints of the input values, since the values cannot be greater than 26 then subtracting `a` from `b` will give you a negative value when `a > b`, in two's complement you know bit `7` will be set in that case - the same applies to `c`.  I then *OR* both so that bit `7` indicates whether `a > b || a > c`, lastly we inspect bit `7` by *AND* with 0x80 and branch on that.

**Update:** Out of curiosity I timed 4 different ways of coding this.  To generate test data I used a simple linear congruential pseudo-random number generator.  I timed it in a loop for 100 million iterations.  I assumed for simplicity that if the condition is true we want to add 5 to a counter, do nothing otherwise.  I timed it using `g++ (GCC) 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2)` on an `Intel Xeon X5570 @ 2.93GHz` using `-O2` optimization level.

Here's the code (comment out all but one of the conditional variants):

```
#include <iostream>
unsigned myrand() {
    static unsigned x = 1;
    return (x = x * 1664525 + 1013904223);
}

int main() {
    size_t count = 0;
    for(size_t i=0; i<100000000; ++i ) {
        int a = 1 + myrand() % 26;
        int b = 1 + myrand() % 26;
        int c = 1 + myrand() % 26;

        count += 5 & (((b-a) | (c-a)) >> 31);       // 0.635 sec
        //if (((b-a) | (c-a)) & 0x80) count += 5;     // 0.660 sec
        //if (a > std::max(b,c)) count += 5;          // 0.677 sec
        //if ( a > b || a > c) count += 5;            // 1.164 sec
    }
    std::cout << count << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The fastest is a modification on the suggestion in my answer, where we use sign extension to generate a mask that is either 32 `1s` or 32 `0s` depending on whether the condition is true of false, and use that to mask the `5` being added so that it either adds 5 or 0.  This variation has no branches.  The times are in a comment on each line.  The slowest was the original expression `( a > b || a > c)`.

Comment: You should make sure the compiler isn't doing this for you. Keep your code simple first, and then micro-optimize only if you can identify a bottleneck.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is probably: you do not want to optimize that. Moreover, I doubt that there's any way to write this more efficiently. If you say that a, b and c are values between 1 and 26, you shouldn't be using integers (you don't need that precision) if you wanted to be optimal (in size) anyway.

If  a > b, the expression a > c will not be executed anyway. So you have at maximum 2 (and at minimum 1) conditional operations, which is really not worth an optimization.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite doubtful this is even an optimisation in most cases.

```
 a > b || a > c
```

will evaluate to:

```
 compare a b
 jump not greater
 compare a c
 jump not greater
```

where

```
 a * 2 > b + c
```

gives:

```
 shift a left 1 (in temp1)
 add b to c (in temp2)
 compare temp1 temp2
 jump if not greater
```

As always with performance, it's always much better to base your decision on actual performance measurements (preferably on a selection of processor architectures).

Comment: Ignoring that reasoning at such level is dangerous and hard -- and almost always pointless to boot -- I'd say that the relative performance of those snippets depends a lot on the. The latter might be easier to pipeline and be nicer to the branch predictor.

Comment: In most cases, the performance difference does not matter at all, or is more easily and accurately determined by benchmarking the specific use case.

Comment: It will works not always. If you will have a = 10, b = 100 and c = 7, then expression a > b || a > c will return true. And your (10*2 > 100 + 7) will return false. Forgive me if I'm wrong =)